Uses of the Mukai vector
Let $X$ be say a smooth projective variety. For $\mathcal{E}^\bullet \in D^b(X)$ the so-called Mukai vector is defined as $$v(\mathcal{E}^\bullet) = \operatorname{ch}(\mathcal{E}^\bullet)\sqrt{\operatorname{td}(X)},$$ where $\operatorname{ch}$ is the Chern character and $\operatorname{td}(X)$ is the Todd class of $X$.
I'm very new to derived categories and their uses in algebraic geometry, but I have hard time finding any motivation for this definition. I apologize in advance, but if anyone here has some good heuristics on why this is a useful thing to consider, I would be very grateful on hearing those.

I know that anyone who can answer will know what it means already, but could you define your notation?

$D^b(X)$ is the derived category of coherent sheaves on $X$ and $\operatorname{ch}$ the Chern character, i.e. a map $K_0(X) \to H^\ast(X,\Bbb Q)$. $\operatorname{td}(X)$ is the Todd class of $X$ @LSpice

Re, right, thanks.  I meant in the post, so I went ahead and edited it in.

The main point is that replacing Chern character by the Mukai vector allows one to get rid of the Todd genus in Riemann--Roch. So, it is not essential, but convenient in many cases.

It also makes the HKR map nicer, right?

I don't know how helpful this will be, since this might raise even more questions. In any case, the Grothendieck-Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem says that
$$\chi(E) = \int_Xch(E)td(X)$$
for any coherent sheaf $E$, or more generally object in $D^b(X)$. If we have another object $F\in D^b(X)$, we can define some sort of intersection number by
$$\langle E,F\rangle = \chi(RHom(E,F)) = \sum (-1)^i \dim Ext^i(E, F)$$
Applying GHRR allows you to compute this as
$$\langle E,F\rangle =\int_X v(E^*)\cup v(F)$$

Donu, I am afraid you confused Grothendieck with Hirzebruch.

Also, in the last formula $v(E)$ should be replaced by $v(E^*)$.

@Sasha OK, yes I should have (and did) add(ed) Hirzebruch's name. Somehow I still feel that G's name should be kept however.
